# How can i use C libraries in Vala? Or how to use g-ir-scanner?

Tags: vala, gobject

How can i use C libraries in Vala? As written in [GNOME documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Bindings), I need to scan my C headers by command line tool [g-ir-scanner](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/g-ir-scanner.1.html) to generate *.GIR file and then generate VAPI (*Vala API*) file with `$ vapigen --library MyLibrary MyLibrary.gir` to use in Vala.

Everything is clear except using [g-ir-scanner](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/g-ir-scanner.1.html). How to use this tool?

Or how to create bindings without this tool?

Comment: "how to create bindings without this tool" You where already very close to the answer -> https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/ManualBindings

Comment: But how to create it automatically? I'm lazy : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"g-ir-scanner is made for libraries built with GObject and has to be used in the source code of the library. For other libraries you unfortunately have to create it by hand. It's best to reuse the ones from here https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala-extra-vapis but if it's not here you have to make it from scratch" (

Answer (score 1):

If using [meson](https://mesonbuild.com/index.html) one can use `gnome.generate_vapi()` documented [here](https://mesonbuild.com/Gnome-module.html#gnomegenerate_vapi)

An eample of it~s usage is [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtksourceview/-/blob/gtksourceview-5-8/gtksourceview/meson.build?ref_type=heads#L307)